# Where to purchase global boundaries data on city level for commercial use?

Tags: extents, administrative-boundaries, commercial

Recently I was asked to deal with an app geo locating improve project. It can't be completed without any boundaries metadata on city level. But so far most of my research led me only to things for non-commercial use.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Actually I was asked to cover 2.5 million cities in the world. And I have absolutely no idea where to start.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your Question to include this relevant detail, please?  Comments are just here to seek clarifications and thus help improve Questions to a more Answer-able state.

Comment: Do you have a reference that supports your/their estimate of 2.5 million cities in the world? It sounds like a LOT more than I would have estimated.

Answer (score 1):

Tom Tom, Nokia, https://www.gfk.com/solutions/geo-marketing/Digital-maps/Pages/Digital-maps.aspx

OSM is a good free option (make sure to comply with license)